# haskell examples often do not work

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I am a beginner in haskell, and using the latest GHCi 2011.2.0.1. One frustration I face frequently is that very often the examples in the internet and books (even from the official haskell.org site, for instance the example-2 of http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad) dont compile. And it takes several rounds of hunting and posting questions to figure out what the problem is. Even some of the examples from the RWH book dont work.

Is this a problem with new version of haskell or of the haskell-platform? Are the language / platform under development and unstable, or only the examples are obsolete? Either way, what is the best way for a new student to find correct examples to learn from?

More specifically, can you help to fix the state monad example mentioned above?

Comment: I know there are a couple haskell books that use Hugs, which is a stable version of Haskell. Perhaps looking more into that will help. Good luck.

Comment: @wespiserA: Huh? Hugs was last updated in 2006, and doesn't implement the latest Haskell standard. I guess it's stable in that it never changes, but it also won't work with basically any modern libraries.

Comment: As I've said before: RWH came out at the wrong time in at least a couple senses.  It was prior to some large changes (exceptions, mtl/transformers), before some major libraries that now might be preferred over the ones used by the book (ex: attoparsec), and was also prior to some small but significant alterations (`instance Monad Either` changed & moved).  This is by no means ment as a knock on the book, but as agreement with the authors notion of a second edition and your question about the rate of change of the language (as implemented and practiced - the specification and core are stable).

Comment: @Rog: you should probably make a separate question for your second question.

Answer (score 9):

In this case, the problem is that the `State` constructor has been removed in newest version of the Monad Transformer Library. If you replace the use of `State` in the definition of `getNext` with `state`, then the program works just fine. (This is because `State` was redefined as `StateT Identity`, i.e. the state monad transformer over the identity monad, and so the separate data-type has been removed. If you don't know what this means, don't worry about it; it just means that you have to replace `State` with `state` whenever you see it.)

Most of the problems with existing examples on the web or in RWH are simply due to new versions of libraries. (I think the main problem with RWH's examples is that the Parsec examples are written for Parsec 2; Parsec 3 changed quite a bit, so at the very least you'll probably need to add some imports.)

In general, Haskell does suffer from not having enough up-to-date, helpful resources; that HaskellWiki page just seems to be unmaintained. (While the HaskellWiki is indeed the official haskell.org site, the pages are written and maintained by the users, so just because something's on the wiki doesn't necessarily mean it's up-to-date or high quality.)

The Monad Transformer Library release that removed `State` was released in October 2010, so it's a shame that there's still a lot of code out there that doesn't work with the new version because of this. Thankfully, the fix is simple.

Comment: Thanks very much, that was very helpful. It is indeed a shame that 2010 code updates are still not reflected in the wiki, and the RWH book is also obsolete. New students very definitely need a new book to learn haskell. Is there any other book/documentation available?

Comment: I like [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) (although it also still has `State` in its code), but there's nothing wrong with RWH, really; apparently the authors are considering writing a new edition. mtl 2 and Parsec 3 are the only major changes that would affect a mostly up-to-date introductory tutorial that I can think of, and the changes to get code working with both should be minor.

Comment: I just fixed that particular bug on the wiki.  Feel free to get an account and fix things as you come across them.